# Equations related to indexing with Numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, indexing

I am trying to make a function that calculates the difference between the previous array and the current array. So the first 2 numbers in the `Numbers` array is `52599, 52575`, the previous number is  `52599` with the label `U` and the current number is  `52575` with the label `L`. Since the current value has the `L` label it will use the equation `L_val` equation `(current_L_pos - previouse_U_pos)/current_L_pos*-100`. Placing the numbers for the equation `(52575 -52599 )/52575 *-100` Which would equal `0.0456`. the calculations will go on like this until the end of the `Numbers` and `Set` array, these arrays have the same length as well. How would i be able to do this with the `np.where()` function and such.

```
Set = np.array(['U' 'L' 'U' 'L' 'U' 'L' 'U' 'L' 'U' 'L' 'U' 'L' 'U' 'L' 'U'])
Numbers = np.array([ 52599  52575  53598 336368 336875 337466 338292 356587 357474 357763 358491 358659 359041 360179 360286])
L_val = (current_L_pos - previouse_U_pos)/current_L_pos*-100
U_val = (previouse_L_pos - current_U_pos)/current_U_pos*-100
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the [np.roll()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) function. You need to be careful with the first and/or last entry, but as long as you handle those edge cases then:

`Numbers - np.roll(Numbers, -1)`

will give you an array of the current number minus the last number.

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I have made another issue relating this post it is an indexing error but it is related to the code above. It would mean a lot if you took a look at it as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65999759/using-multiple-functions-with-correlated-arrays-numpy-python

Comment: Hey @Tony, if the answers work here and/or the other post, please accept so the community knows to move on. Thanks!