# using multiple functions with correlated arrays Numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, where-clause

The function below is supposed compute either the `Uval` and `Lval` functions in accordance to `Set` and `Numbers`. For the first two numbers `U` and `52599` are in relation and `L` and `52550` are in relation, since the second number has the label `L` the `Lval` equation is used. The previous number is function is `previous = numbers[1:]` and the current function is `current = numbers[:-1]`. So `(52550 - 52599)/52550 * -100` will be the computation for the first two numbers. The equations are supposed to be computed until the end of the `Set` and `Numbers` arrays. However the code gives me the error down below, both the `Set` and `Numbers` array have the length of 15.

Function:

```
Set = np.array(['U', 'L', 'U', 'L', 'U', 'L', 'U', 'L', 'U', 'L', 'U', 'L', 'U', 'L', 'U'])
Numbers = np.array([ 52599, 52550, 53598, 336368, 336875, 337466, 338292, 356587, 357474, 357763, 358491, 358659, 359041, 360179, 360286])
Lval = (Numbers[:-1] - Numbers[1:])/Numbers[:-1] * -100
Uval = (Numbers[1:] - Numbers[:-1])/ Numbers[1:] * -100
Numbers * np.where(Set == 'U', Uval, Lval)
```

Error Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-3ddad609950b> in <module>
      4 Uval = (Numbers[1:] - Numbers[:-1])/ Numbers[1:] * -100
      5 print(len(Set))
----> 6 Numbers * np.where(Set == 'U', Uval, Lval)

<__array_function__ internals> in where(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (15,) (14,) (14,)
```

Comment: Since you are subctracting each element from the previous (or from the subsequent), the shape of Uval and Lval is (14, ) not (15, ).
You can try to add padding (I mean, decide what is the previous value for the first element and the subsequent value for the last one)  or to select Numbers[1:] or Numbers[:-1] (same for Set) in the last computation.
I think use padding is the best solution in your case. Computation made with padding will be discarded.

Comment: Could you perhaps give an example of padding i am not sure that I completely understand the concept.

Comment: yes. First, I suggest you to read the answer of BLimitless. I think he noticed a crucial point. Then, in order to handle edges, you coud add fake values to Numbers array at the first and the last position. `Numbers = np.array([ 1, 52599, 52550, ..., 360179, 360286, 1])` Fake values depend on your context. In this way you are defining a previous value for the first element and a subsequent value for the last one. When you apply where, just discard padding values `Numbers[1:-1] * np.where(Set == 'U', Uval, Lval)`

Answer (score 1):

your slice notation isn't doing what you think it is:

```
in: Numbers[:-1]
```

does *not* shift elements in the array by 1. It takes all elements up to but not including the last element. The output is:

```
in: Numbers[:-1] 
out: array([ 52599,  52550,  53598, 336368, 336875, 337466, 338292, 356587,
   357474, 357763, 358491, 358659, 359041, 360179])
```

That is every element in Numbers except for the last, 360286.

You need to use the np.roll() function to shift elements by one. This will roll the last element to the front though:

```
in: np.roll(Numbers, 1)
out: array([360286,  52599,  52550,  53598, 336368, 336875, 337466, 338292,
   356587, 357474, 357763, 358491, 358659, 359041, 360179])
```

so you have to handle the edge case of what to do with the very first and very last numbers, e.g. your arrays are length 15, so you can only get 14 new elements for either L or U.